# Laravel - Unit Testing with SoftDeletes

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, unit-testing

I have a basic test which verifies that a user can only see its own posts.

In my test_database I whip up a couple posts, attach some of them to the user with the ModelFactory - which I then test that this user can only see the posts that are linked to the user according to the 'user_id' column in the post records. The test basically asserts that the output of a query is as expected.

- I'm using the SoftDeletes trait in my Post model.
- I have 'deleted_at' in the 'protected $dates' property on Post Model.

The problem is that the 'deleted_at' field is NOT returned in the factory()->create() output - but it IS present in the query where I fetch all the user's posts.

I was able to solve this by adding the 'deleted_at' field to the factory with value null, but it seems silly to me to have to add this field to every factory.

Why do I explicitly need to do this for 'deleted_at' but not for example for 'created_at' and 'updated_at'?

**Code**

Post schema

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('locale_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->text('description')->nullable();
    $table->boolean('active')->default(false);
    $table->datetime('start_date')->nullable()->default(null);
    $table->datetime('end_date')->nullable()->default(null);

    $table->softDeletes();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Post factory

```
$factory->define(App\Post::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'company_id' => function () {
            return factory(App\Company::class)->create()->id;
        },
        'locale_id' => function () {
            return factory(App\Locale::class)->create()->id;
        },
        'title' => $faker->sentence(rand(1,3)),
        'body' => $faker->paragraph(1),
        'active' => rand(0,1),
        'start_date' => $faker->dateTimeBetween('now', '+2 years')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'end_date' => $faker->dateTimeBetween('+2 years', '+4 years')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ];
});
```

My unit test

```
public function test_scope_foruser_only_returns_posts_for_authenticated_user()
{
    // Given there are 2 companies
    $companies = factory(Company::class, 2)->create();

    // With 1 post per company
    $postX = factory(Post::class)->create(['company_id' => $companies->first()->id]);
    $postY = factory(Post::class)->create(['company_id' => $companies->last()->id]);

    // Given I am logged in as user of the first company
    $user = factory(User::class)->create([
        'typeable_type' => Company::class,
        'typeable_id' => $companies->first()->id
    ]);

    // Login
    $this->be(User::first());

    // When I fetch the posts for User (via company)
    $posts = Post::forUser()->get()->toArray();


    // Then It returns only posts which the user's company
    // is associated with in a properly formatted array
    $this->assertCount(1, $posts);
    $this->assertEquals([$postX->toArray()], $posts);
}
```

This is the query scope applied to the Post model as seen above

```
public function scopeForUser($query)
{
    if ($company = auth()->user()->company) {
        return $query->where(['company_id' => $company->id]);
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the query you are using

Comment: @RohitDalal I've updated my question.

Comment: You haven't added any example for the `deleted_at` field and how it is a problem for your factory and query.

Comment: The deleted_at field is a problem for my unit test.. in which the value of $postX->toArray() is missing the 'deleted_at' field compared to the one value in $posts

Comment: Do you have it in the ModelFactory file for Post?

Comment: Not in the ModelFactory, but neither are 'created_at' and 'updated_at'. So what makes 'deleted_at' special? I've added the factory to my question.

Comment: I'm not sure but it has to do with the `toArray()` method which has some logic for which fields to be included to the array casting.

Comment: But the values I am comparing are both casted to arrays... So the logic and thus the contents of its output would be the same, no?